# Desktop is unresponsive for a minute after copying shortcut to desktop

Tags: windows-8.1

When I copy a shortcut to my desktop, the desktop becomes unresponsive for 30 seconds to a minute. I can't click on any shortcuts, right-click desktop, open start menu, open charms bar, nothing. (If I copy a larger file of 50 MB though, it doesn't hang the desktop during and after the copy.)

After 30 seconds to a minute, everything goes back to normal and it works fine. If I have the Task Manager open when I do the copy (it is still actively updating), it shows no extra CPU usage, RAM usage spike, network usage or disk usage.

Why would copying a a 1-2 KB shortcut make the desktop unresponsive while copying a 50 MB file doesn't?

Comment: "Why would copying a a 1-2 KB shortcut make the desktop unresponsive while copying a 50 MB file doesn't?" - I would assume that size has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Ah... I've had similar in programming, it was either the AV or Windows Defender. It was a long time, I don't remember details (some thing like Windows locked the file for moving but left a handle or similar, and the AV had to wait for it to be released before it could finish the scan, which ironically didn't happen on bigger files probably due to scanning after the file was copied... any way, long time ago). Can you try disabling your AV/Firewall and Defender etc to see if the same issue persists?

Comment: I don't have a AV/Firewall running. I'll try turning off Defender.

Comment: Do you get the same issue when you [start Windows in Safe Mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-computer-safe-mode#start-computer-safe-mode=windows-7) or [perform a clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us)?